# Is there a more upto date guide for civicase?

Tags: civicase, documentation

I'm currently trying to learn more about how to make civicase work better for us but there is only the https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/case-management/ available which I understand is out of date.  Does anyone know if there is something else available.

TIA

Comment: There haven't been many significant changes to CiviCase - there have been attempts at 'improvements' eg this Extension  https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicase-v5 - and there is also this https://civicrm.org/blog/jamienovick/civicase-new-way-manage-cases-using-civicrm, but the fundamentals of out-of-the-box CiviCase should pretty well match the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give specifics on what you think is out of date. Filing issues or pull requests to update anything that's wrong are always welcome since it's entirely maintained by volunteers.

See https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting

You can also post about any specific issue you're trying to solve and someone here might come up with a suggestion.